# Entity Framework 5 SaveChanges Not Working, No Error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-sql

None of the many questions on this topic seem to match my situation. I have a large data model. In certain cases, only a few of the fields need be displayed on the UI, so for those I replaced the LINQ to Entity query that pulls in everything with an Entity SQL query retrieving only the columns needed, using a Type constructor so that I got an entity returned and not a DbDataRecord, like this:

```
SELECT VALUE MyModelNameSpace.INCIDENT(incident.FieldA, incident.FieldB, ...) FROM ... AS ...
```

This works and displays the fields in the UI. And if I make a change, the change makes it back to the entity model when I tab out of the UI element. But when I do a SaveChanges, the changes do not get persisted to the database. No errors show up in the Log. Now if I very carefully replace the above query with an Entity Sql query that retrieves the entire entity, like this:

```
SELECT VALUE incident FROM MyDB.INCIDENTs AS incident...
```

Changes do get persisted in the database! So as a test, I created another query like the first that named every column in the entity, which should be the exact equivalent of the second Entity SQL query. Yet it did not persist changes to the database either.

I've tried setting the MergeOption on the returned result to PreserveChanges, to start tracking, like this:

```
incidents.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
```

But that has no effect. But really, if retrieving the entire entity with Entity Sql persists changes, what logical purpose would there be for behaving differently when a subset of the fields are retrieved? I'm wondering if this is a bug?

Comment: I _think_ it is the same difference as just newing an `Incident` in code or fetching it from the collection in the context. The first instance is not tracked, because the context doesn't know about it.

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but I forgot to show that the returned value, ObjectQuery<INCIDENT>, is passed into the CollectionViewSource object. That's why the data populates the fields, changes are pushed back into the entity fields.

Comment: Thanks. But if that's it, how do I make the context aware?  I thought MergeOption.PreserveChanges would ensure that, but it has no effect.

Comment: You have to `Attach` the entity to the context.

Comment: You are correct. The EntityState was Detached. Took me hours to figure out how to attach it, however. Kept running into things like EntityKey was null, can't attach an object with a null key, etc, but figured it out. Will add details to show what worked. Question:  how do I give you credit for the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Give credit? You already did :D. You can accept your own answer, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Gert was correct, the problem was that the entity was not attached. *Dank U wel, Gert! Ik was ervan verbluft!*
I just wanted to add a little detail to show the full solution. Basically, the ObjectContext has an Attach method, so you'd think that would be it. However, when your Entity SQL select statement names columns, and you create the object using a Type as I did, the EntityKey is not created, and ObjectContext.Attach fails. After trying and failing to insert the EntityKey I created myself, I stumbled across ObjectSet.Attach, added in Entity Framework 4. Instead of failing, it creates the EntityKey if it is missing.  Nice touch.

The code was (this can probably be done in fewer steps, but I know this works):

```
var QueryString = "SELECT VALUE RunTimeUIDesigner.INCIDENT  (incident.INCIDENT_NBR,incident.LOCATION,etc"
ObjectQuery<INCIDENT> incidents = orbcadDB.CreateQuery<INCIDENT>(QueryString);
incidents.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
List<INCIDENT> retrievedIncidents = incidents.ToList<INCIDENT>();
orbcadDB.INCIDENTs.Attach(retrievedIncidents[0]);
iNCIDENTsViewSource.Source = retrievedIncidents;
```